# How to solve minify js and css first time load delay?

Tags: cache

**Scenario:** 
 - My site pages and most pages usually loads around 3s to 5s. 
 - I have a lot of posts on my site and new posts are added every 12 hours. I did not use any on site caching plugin to avoid large diskspace usage for cache files.
 - I am using cloudflare cache with expiry set to 8hours so that my front page, categories and archive pages can be updated with fresh contents accordingly.

**Problem:** 
 - I wanted to improve my google page speed score and tried to run plugins like autoptimize which can auto minify and defer render blocking of css and js. 
 - These plugins improved my page rank score tremendously for cached pages.
 - However these plguins actually made my site slower as they add 5 to 10
   seconds to first load of uncached pages for them to do their minifying and cache writing.(My cache expire every 8 hours)

**Question:** 
Under my scenario, is there a way that I able to retain/improve my usual site speed and satisfy pagespeed minify and script defer requirement?

Comment: You could build a cache warmer and let it run on crons to cURL all URLs in your sitemap or something like that.

Comment: You can minify and defer by hand,  plugins such as autoptimise aren't needed and are more like a brute force hammer approach ( they also cripple your TTFB times etc ), but keep in mind that minifying javascript and CSS isn't a WP question, and would be better asked on stackoverflow, and that sometimes deferring a script doesn't improve performance ( e.g. if your site requires jQuery to display things, deferring it may not be so useful ). Page speed is a guide, not a law, if you're doing this for SEO purposes, it goes off of the loading times, not the things in the pagespeed tests

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Tom J Nowell. I have followed your advice and manually minify .js and .css files before hand, instead of using a plugin to do it for me everytime the page loads. Like you said do not used a brute force hammer.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to reduce your typical 3-5s loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used speed booster plugin to defer javascript and inline CSS. For minifying, I manually minify the .js script and .css files before hand. This helped to improve my pagespeed score without going through first load issue.

Like Tom J Nowell suggested, do not use brute force hammer approach by using plugins like autoptimize which actually made the task more complex.

Comment: You can accept your own answer with a check mark as solution.